# Why are solder pad layouts in datasheets always drawn up so unintuitively?

Tags: pcb-design, altium, eaglecad, kicad, footprint

I am making a PCB that is using parts that require me to draw up custom footprints. So far, all the parts I've come across have the most seemingly stupid selection of measurements for pads. Take this tac switch layout for example:

[image]

For a layout as simple as this, I find it absolutely befuddling that they give no direct numbers of pad sizes and locations. Instead I have to do a series of equations to find the number I need. Yes they are quick and easy, but this introduces margins for error, and increasingly for the number of parts you draw. Why would they not opt for a layout like this:

[image]

I've only had experience with KiCad and Eagle, and both those programs locate pads via the centre (I'd imagine Altium and others would work the same).

**Why do manufacturer represent their footprints in such a roundabout way, not directly providing the numbers that the programs they are designed for need?** I feel as though I am either missing something, or going about footprint design incorrectly.

Comment: If it's anything like machining drawings, it's because when you have the actual workpiece in front of you, the first method is more easily and more directly measured than the second, even though the second is more straightforward to lay out. For example, it might be easier to position a circle in CAD software based on center coordinates and radius but when you have the circle in front of you you would be hard pressed to locate the center of the circle before measuring the distance from the center to the edge. It's much more direct to measure the diameter.

Comment: I would have no problem entering that design into freecad using those numbers, but freecad is not how I draw footprints.

Comment: My guess is that they just abide to the industrial/engineering dimensioning standards. Standards sometimes appear to be silly (and from time to time they are) but their reasoning is most of the time sound.